# Mostrar la información en Listview dependiendo la selección de un spinner?

Tags: android, firebase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Como llamar al hijo de una tabla en `firebase` y mostrar la información en `Listview` dependiendo la selección de un `spinner`?

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.myfirstapp.modelo.CuestionarioInformation;
import com.example.myfirstapp.modelo.PreguntasInformation;
import com.example.myfirstapp.modelo.activityCInformation;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MD_CuestionarioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edtPregunta;
    ListView listView_preguntas;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    Spinner mSpinnerMD;

    private List<PreguntasInformation> listPreguntas = new ArrayList<PreguntasInformation>();
    private ArrayAdapter<PreguntasInformation> arrayAdapterPreguntas;

    private List<CuestionarioInformation> listCuestionario2 = new ArrayList<CuestionarioInformation>();
    private ArrayAdapter<CuestionarioInformation> arrayAdapterCuestionario2;

    PreguntasInformation preguntaSeleccionada;
    CuestionarioInformation cuestionarioSeleccionada;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_md__cuestionario);

        edtPregunta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPregunta);
        listView_preguntas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_cuestionariosMD);
        mSpinnerMD = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        eventoDatabase1();
        eventoDatabase();
        listView_preguntas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                preguntaSeleccionada = (PreguntasInformation) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CEE3F6"));
                edtPregunta.setText(preguntaSeleccionada.getPregunta());
                mSpinnerMD.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

    }

    private void eventoDatabase() {
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
        PreguntasInformation p = new PreguntasInformation();
        databaseReference.child("Preguntas").child(mSpinnerMD.getSelectedItem().toString()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                listPreguntas.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    PreguntasInformation p = objSnapshot.getValue(PreguntasInformation.class);
                    listPreguntas.add(p);
                }
                arrayAdapterPreguntas = new ArrayAdapter<PreguntasInformation>(MD_CuestionarioActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listPreguntas);
                listView_preguntas.setAdapter(arrayAdapterPreguntas);
                listPreguntas.clear();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void eventoDatabase1() {
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
        databaseReference.child("Cuestionarios").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                listCuestionario2.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    CuestionarioInformation p = objSnapshot.getValue(CuestionarioInformation.class);
                    listCuestionario2.add(p);
                }
                arrayAdapterCuestionario2 = new ArrayAdapter<CuestionarioInformation>(MD_CuestionarioActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  listCuestionario2);
                mSpinnerMD.setAdapter(arrayAdapterCuestionario2);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_cuestionarios, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.menu_agregar){
            String pregunta= edtPregunta.getText().toString().trim();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pregunta)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Por favor, introduzca la pregunta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else {
                PreguntasInformation p = new PreguntasInformation();
                p.setNameC(mSpinnerMD.getSelectedItem().toString());
                p.setUidC(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                p.setPregunta(edtPregunta.getText().toString());
                databaseReference.child("Preguntas").child(p.getNameC()).child(p.getUidC()).setValue(p.getPregunta()).equals(p.nameC);
                limpiarCampos();
            }
        }else if(id == R.id.menu_actualiza) {
            if (preguntaSeleccionada == null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Por favor, seleccione una fila", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (preguntaSeleccionada != null){
                PreguntasInformation p = new PreguntasInformation();
                p.setUidC(preguntaSeleccionada.getUidC());
                p.setPregunta(edtPregunta.getText().toString().trim());
                databaseReference.child("Preguntas").child(p.getUidC()).child(p.getUidC());
            }
            limpiarCampos();
            //Sí se selecciona el icono eliminar
        }else if(id == R.id.menu_deleta) {
            if (preguntaSeleccionada == null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Por favor, seleccione una fila", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (preguntaSeleccionada != null) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertDialog.setMessage("Desea eliminar esta pregunta?");
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        PreguntasInformation p = new PreguntasInformation();
                        p.setUidC(preguntaSeleccionada.getUidC());
                        databaseReference.child("Cuestionarios").child(p.getUidC()).removeValue();
                        limpiarCampos();
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void limpiarCampos() {
        eventoDatabase1();
        edtPregunta.setText("");
        mSpinnerMD.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

**class PreguntasInformation**

```
package com.example.myfirstapp.modelo;

public class PreguntasInformation {
    public String activi;
    public String uidC;
    public String nameC;
    public String pregunta;

    public PreguntasInformation() {
    }

    public PreguntasInformation(String uidC, String nameC, String pregunta) {
        this.uidC = uidC;
        this.nameC = nameC;
        this.pregunta = pregunta;
    }

public String getActivi() {
    return activi;
}

public void setActivi(String activi) {
    this.activi = activi;
}

public String getUidC() {
    return uidC;
}

public void setUidC(String uidC) {
    this.uidC = uidC;
}

public String getNameC() {
    return nameC;
}

public void setNameC(String nameC) {
    this.nameC = nameC;
}

public String getPregunta() {
    return pregunta;
}

public void setPregunta(String pregunta) {
    this.pregunta = pregunta;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ""+pregunta;
}

}
```

Comment: Hola Kar, ¿cual es el problema que tienes en el código?, ¿Mensaje de error?. Revisar [ask]. Con respecto a tus preguntas anteriores ninguna respuesta te ayudo?

Comment: Hola Jorgesys en el método eventoDatabase() quiero mandar a llamar a una tabla hijo que se encuentra adentro de la principal por así decirlo y en la listview salga los datos según la selección del spinner. Soy nueva en firebase y no puedo entender como hacer las consultas.

Comment: podrias pegar la clase PreguntasInformation ? gracias

Comment: que pasa si le pasas preguntaSeleccionada  al child de eventoDatabase , que te quede databaseReference.child("Preguntas").child(preguntaSeleccionada ).... ya que le pasarias la pregunta que queres seleccionar para obtener los hijos de ahi

Comment: @GastónSaillén me sale este error    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.myfirstapp.modelo.CuestionarioInformation.getNameC()' on a null object reference